# Shave off decimal of large numbers javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a function to *Prettify* my numbers it seems to be very glitch for example 400 displays as 4H which is right 430 displays as 4.3H still acceptable but 403 displays as 4.03H which is not acceptable here is my code not sure what to do to fix it

**EDIT:** As numbers get larger say 5003 they will display as 5.003K I want it to display 5K
**EDIT:** As numbers get larger say 5003 they will display as 5.003K I want it to display 5K
Basically the decimal place should never be more then 2
like heres a list

```
5000 -> 5K
5500 -> 5.5k
5050 -> 5.05k
5005 -> 5K
```

```js
var ranges = [
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Dec' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Non' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Oct' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Sep' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Sex' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Quin' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000 , suffix: 'Quad' },
    { divider: 1000000000000 , suffix: 'T' },
    { divider: 1000000000 , suffix: 'B' },
    { divider: 1000000 , suffix: 'M' },
    { divider: 1000 , suffix: 'K' },
    { divider: 100 , suffix: 'H' }
];

function INP(number, round) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    if (number >= ranges[i].divider) {
      if (round == null) {
        return (number / ranges[i].divider) + ranges[i].suffix;
      } else {
        return (number / ranges[i].divider).toFixed(round) + ranges[i].suffix;
      }
    }
  }
  return number.toString();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number" id="num" placeholder="number">
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="rounded" placeholder="round">
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
<script>
  var field = document.getElementById("num");
  var div = document.getElementById("output");

  field.onkeyup = function() {
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    var rounded = document.getElementById("rounded").value;

    if (rounded == true) {
      var output = INP(num, true);
    } else {
      var output = INP(num);
    }

    div.innerHTML = "Output: " + output;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So how do you define if it is acceptable or not?

Comment: So you want at most 1 digit after the decimal?

Comment: take a look at my edit @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some bugs in your code

1. `if (rounded == true)` it will be always false the input value of number field never become `true`.
2. `INP(num, true)` you are passing `true` as the argument, there is nothing to do with that. Expected parameter is a number as per your code.
3. `if (round == null)` also always false, if the second input field is empty value would be empty string not null so change it to `if (round == '')`

```js
var ranges = [{
  divider: 1000000000000000000000000000000000,
  suffix: 'Dec'
}, {
  divider: 1000000000000000000000000000000,
  suffix: 'Non'
}, {
  divider: 1000000000000000000000000000,
  suffix: 'Oct'
}, {
  divider: 1000000000000000000000000,
  suffix: 'Sep'
}, {
  divider: 1000000000000000000000,
  suffix: 'Sex'
}, {
  divider: 1000000000000000000,
  suffix: 'Quin'
}, {
  divider: 1000000000000000,
  suffix: 'Quad'
}, {
  divider: 1000000000000,
  suffix: 'T'
}, {
  divider: 1000000000,
  suffix: 'B'
}, {
  divider: 1000000,
  suffix: 'M'
}, {
  divider: 1000,
  suffix: 'K'
}, {
  divider: 100,
  suffix: 'H'
}];

function INP(number, round) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    if (number >= ranges[i].divider) {
      if (round == '') {
        return (number / ranges[i].divider) + ranges[i].suffix;
      } else {
        var res = (number / ranges[i].divider).toFixed(round),
          fr = res - parseInt(res, 10);
        return (fr > 0 ? res : parseInt(res, 10)) + ranges[i].suffix;
      }
    }
  }
  return number.toString();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number" id="num" placeholder="number">
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="rounded" placeholder="round">
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
<script>
  var field = document.getElementById("num");
  var div = document.getElementById("output");

  field.onkeyup = function() {
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    var rounded = document.getElementById("rounded").value;

    var output = INP(num, rounded);

    div.innerHTML = "Output: " + output;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @JoséphFlames : I have updated it, if second input is empty do want to show the exact output.... with all decimal parts

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, `if (rounded == true)` doesn't do what you want. `rounded` is a string, and comparing a string to a boolean converts the boolean to a string, which results in the string `"1"`, so it's equivalent to `if (rounded == "1")`. You can use `parseInt()` to convert the input to an integer, then use `if (rounded)`.

Second, you weren't passing the value of `rounded` to `INP`, you were passing `true`. Then when it used this in `toFixed()` it converted to the integer `1`, so it always rounds to 1 decimal place instead of the number in the `rounded` input.

To get rid of extra trailing zeroes on the result of `toFixed`, call `parseFloat()` on it to convert it back to a number.

```js
var ranges = [
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Dec' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Non' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Oct' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Sep' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Sex' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000000 , suffix: 'Quin' },
    { divider: 1000000000000000 , suffix: 'Quad' },
    { divider: 1000000000000 , suffix: 'T' },
    { divider: 1000000000 , suffix: 'B' },
    { divider: 1000000 , suffix: 'M' },
    { divider: 1000 , suffix: 'K' },
    { divider: 100 , suffix: 'H' }
];

function INP(number, round) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    if (number >= ranges[i].divider) {
      if (round == null) {
        return (number / ranges[i].divider) + ranges[i].suffix;
      } else {
        return parseFloat((number / ranges[i].divider).toFixed(round)) + ranges[i].suffix;
      }
    }
  }
  return number.toString();
}

var field = document.getElementById("num");
var div = document.getElementById("output");

field.onkeyup = function() {
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value, 10);
  var rounded = parseInt(document.getElementById("rounded").value, 10);

  if (rounded) {
    var output = INP(num, rounded);
  } else {
    var output = INP(num);
  }

  div.innerHTML = "Output: " + output;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number" id="num" placeholder="number">
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="rounded" placeholder="round">
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like the INP function to put out the correct number all the html and other javascript is just for debugging

Comment: You have to call it with the correct arguments. `round` is supposed to be the number of decimal places, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the unit prefix with logarithm of 10. The apply adjustment and use it.

```js
var ranges = { 33: 'Dec', 30: 'Non', 27: 'Oct', 24: 'Sep', 21: 'Sex', 18: 'Quin', 15: 'Quad', 12: 'T', 9: 'B', 6: 'M', 3: 'K', 2: 'H' };

function INP(number, round) {
    var exp = Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(10));
    while (exp > 3 && !ranges[exp]) {
        exp--;
    }
    if (!ranges[exp]) {
        return number.toString();
    }
    return round === '' ?
        (number / Math.pow(10, exp)) + ranges[exp] :
        (number / Math.pow(10, exp)).toFixed(round) + ranges[exp];
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number" id="num" placeholder="number">
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="rounded" placeholder="round">
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
<script>
  var field = document.getElementById("num");
  var div = document.getElementById("output");

  field.onkeyup = function() {
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    var rounded = document.getElementById("rounded").value;

    var output = INP(num, rounded);
    div.innerHTML = "Output: " + output;
  }
</script>
```